Sand paper installation on Craftsman 1/2 sheet sander
How to load sandpaper on an old Sears Best half sheet sander? I don't see any levers to push or pull. Do I use adhesive-backed papers? Model 126162.

IIRC, it doesn't take adhesive-backed papers, but I can't quite remember how to do it.  You're right, it's not obvious, until you know how! Then, it's simple.  Can you post a photo of it?  Maybe it will jog a few neurons...

The sander I had used rollers you turn with a screwdriver to tighten the paper on.

A picture of both ends of the sanding pad may help us get you some answers. Also, are you sure of the model number? 126162 doesn't return much on Google, but 116162 does. My dad had a sander like the 116162, and like Crip659 above, I also remember the screwdriver-driven rollers one turned to draw in the end of the sandpaper. There's pictures of the 116162 that show a lever one rotates out to tip up and open a spring-loaded clip to stick the paper in.

I have one hat that uses spring clips which need to be pulled open with a screwdriver or similar. Yes, photos would help.
